# Traffic Routing On Linux

Tags: routes, iptables, traffic

I have three computers on the same network (A, B, and C).  B has 2 interfaces.  I want A->C traffic to be routed through B.  I believe I can do this by having A send traffic to B, and B mangles the destination address to C.

I have tried getting this to work using the following on B:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i [B_INTERFACE] -j DNAT --to [C_IP]
```

But the traffic does not route to C.

I understand this command to basically change the destination IP address of the IP traffic to [C_IP] for all traffic incoming on [B_INTERFACE].  Is this wrong?  If so, what command would do that?  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try route command on A. Basically add B as default getaway on A to first interface. Connect C to 2nd interface of B and use iptable foward chain on B to C or prerouting. Or add default getway C on B. Done!

Comment: This is what I ended up having to do.  I would have preferred some solution that only required changes to B, however.  But this worked for me, so thanks!